# Can a mapping $M: \mathbb{U}\rightarrow\mathbb{V}$ be one to one if $\mathbb{U}$ is of a higher dimension than $\mathbb{V}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I don't think so, here is my intuitive reasioning:

$1$: If $\mathbb{U}$ is of a higher dimension, then all of $\mathbb{V}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{U}$.

$2$: Let $M$ map all of this subset of $\mathbb{U}\rightarrow \mathbb{V}$ in a one to one manner

$3$: Now let $M$ map any other element of $\mathbb{U}\rightarrow \mathbb{V}$

$4$: There are now two elements of $\mathbb{U}$ that correspond to the same element of $\mathbb{V}$ and $M$ is not one to one

This intution is based on $\mathbb{R}^n$. For instance, a plane contains every line on it. However I'm unsure if this reasoning extends to more general cases.

Comment: So these are vector spaces?  And $M$ is linear?

Comment: yeah, I thought of this while thinking about vector spaces, but I'm also wondering if I'm correct, what other kinds of sets this could apply to

Comment: Line 1 is wrong as $\mathbb{V}$ need not be a subspace of $\mathbb{U}$.

Comment: Thats true, maybe subspace/set wasn't the right word there

Comment: It is not true in general. There are bijections between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$. To exclude these examples, you need to assume that $M$ has some regularity. For example continuity would be enough (google invariance of domain).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Great thanks for the help

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Given that the question is tagged as linear algebra, “linear” seems to be a better (and also helpful) restriction

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Indeed, I did not look at the tags. But given that linear maps are continuous (at least in finite dimensions), that should not do too much harm :)